# Python and aggressive-indent

Tags: indentation, python

I am trying to use `aggressive-indent`, which I find great, but when I am writing Python code it doesn't seem to work (although general it works fine). I may miss something in the usage of `aggressive-indent`, making this my fault, but I can't see why. Can someone see what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggressive-indent intentionally disables itself on major modes where it wouldn't make sense. `python-mode` is one of them.

The problem is that indentation is not absolute in python, so Emacs has no way of performing it automatically.

You can disable this safeguard (at your own risk) with:

```
(setq aggressive-indent-excluded-modes
      (remove 'python-mode aggressive-indent-excluded-modes))
```

Comment: I thought that this was my fault. Thank you!

Comment: That option does not show up.  I am on emacs 23.1.1 on rhel: is that version too old?

Comment: @javadba Yes, aggressive-indent requires Emacs 24.

Comment: Is there any adverse effects in using `aggressive-indent` in `latex-mode`?.